# android tablayout - how to use a button instead of tab indicators to trigger click event?

Tags: android

so i have a standard tabLayout that is in a viewpager.

But the very last tab needs to open a new activity. its only purpose is to open a new activity.  and when the user returns from the activity by pressing the back button the last tab the user was at should be selected.

my tabs are custom views and there are 4 of them but the last one should be a button to trigger an event. so it will look just like a tab but really will be a button with a onclick listener. how can i acheive this ? i am wondering if a framelayout could be used and activated for the very last tab icon . thats the only way i can see to do it is to get the custom view and set its parent to be clickable that way it absorbs the click event. then i can set a onclick listener on the parent to open the activity. but then how to handle swipping to that tab ? swipping should open that activity as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you're using `TabLayout.setupWithViewPager()`, you can accomplish what you want by simply adding an extra tab and changing the `OnTabSelectedListener`.

```
    // normal setup
    tabs.setupWithViewPager(pager);

    // our extra tab
    tabs.addTab(tabs.newTab().setText("extra"));

    // remove the `OnTabSelectedListener` created by `setupWithViewPager()`
    tabs.clearOnTabSelectedListeners();

    // add our own `OnTabSelectedListener`
    tabs.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.ViewPagerOnTabSelectedListener(pager) {

        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            if (tab.getPosition() == pager.getAdapter().getCount()) {
                // special case for the last tab in the list
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, OtherActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
            else {
                // otherwise, handle as normal
                super.onTabSelected(tab);
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Will this be a infinite loop. After user presses ok as last tab and then hits back button they will arrive on last tab again. It's either a loop or maybe a blank page right.  How to avoid

Comment: Neither. Clicking the last tab launches an activity, it doesn't set the tab or page or anything. I wrote a small sample app with this solution and it worked perfectly.

Comment: If you're on the last page (and therefore the second-to-last tab), you can't swipe any farther. Swiping just brings up the overscroll image. You have to actually click on the last tab to open the activity. But you can swipe between the real pages just fine.